# Service unable to send sms through build-in app

Tags: android

I have an application with only a service. Following is my code of the service, it is unable to call the device's build-in sms app.

```
public class smsservice extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "MyService";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "Service created.");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("TAG", "Service started.");
    try {

        String sb = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("dest1");
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", sb);
        sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        startActivity(sendIntent);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("slog", "onDestroy()");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

I have include the permission in the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Is there something I am missing or is it even possible

Answer (score 0):

> I have an application with only a service

First, I hope you have a plan for something to run your service. By default, nothing in your app will ever run.

Second, I hope that you can afford security guards. Since you have no activity, the only way anything will ever cause your service to run is if your service is exported. Unless you have some special tricks in mind, this means that any app can ask your service to send an SMS. If this gets exploited, your users may come after you, with guns and knives and so forth.

Third, there is no requirement for an Android device to support sending an SMS via `ACTION_VIEW`, let alone using some undocumented `Intent` extras. Use `ACTION_SEND` or `ACTION_SENDTO`.

> it is unable to call the device's build-in sms app.

If you look at LogCat, I am guessing that you will see an error message mentioning that you need to add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to the `Intent` to be able to start it from a service. You need to call `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` on the `Intent`, before calling `startService()`.

That is because popping up an activity in the middle of whatever the user is doing usually is inappropriate. You do not know if the user is doing something with their device, when all of a sudden, your activity takes over the foreground. Users may also come after you with guns and knives for interrupting their game, their movie, their navigation instructions, etc. Hence, you should hire some security guards.

> I have include the permission in the manifest file

That is for sending an SMS via `SmsManager`. You should not need it for `ACTION_SEND` or `ACTION_SENDTO`.

Comment: I am calling this service through another app by explicit intent. Yes the service is exported. Do I need  to call addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) on the Intent, before calling startActivity() or startService() in the app thats calling the service

Comment: @mine0901: The `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` gets called on the `Intent` that you plan to pass to `startActivity()`.